# In mongodb, what's the time complexity of searching for a document having an element in a list?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a users collection:

```
{
   name: "sue"
   age:  27
   groups: ["football", "hockey"]
}
...

db.users.find( { groups: 'hockey' } )
```

Does mongodb need to visit each list element in each document?

More generally, is there a guide to the time cost for operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an index on the users collection:

```
db.users.ensureIndex( {"groups" : 1} )
```

If you do so, mongodb will not visit each element in the groups field when you run the search. Use

```
  db.users.find( { groups: 'hockey' } ).explain()
```

to see the indexes used.

Depending on the query, it may not need to retrieve the user record at all.  For example,

```
db.users.count( { groups: "hockey"} )
```

is a "covered query" and can be answered using the index alone.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/ for more information.